# Reason for this bash redirection behaviour

Tags: bash

Why `echo a > file1 > file2` creates both files but only write to `file2`? (`file1` is empty.)

Comment: if you need to write into both files, use `echo a | tee file1 > file2` .Good luck.

Comment: sorry typo!  @shelter is right.

Comment: @shelter thanks but I knew that. also `echo a | tee file1 file2` works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because I/O redirections are processed from left to right. The sequence of actions is:

1. Open `file1` for writing (creating it if it doesn't exist).
2. Redirect `stdout` to `file1`.
3. Open `file2` for writing (creating it if it doesn't exist).
4. Redirect `stdout` to `file2`.
5. Run `echo a`.